# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified Error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sqlexception

I am trying to connect Oracle Database with JDBC Driver. I am getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified error. Please help me in resolving the issue.

```java
package test_connection;

import java.sql.*;

public class TestConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded successfully ");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin@:localhost:1521:XE", username, password);
            System.out.println("Connection established successfully ");

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace of the error.

```
run:
Driver loaded successfully 
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: @Sam previously I have already tried without same colon before ampersand. But that was leading to same error.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the error here, to better debug and answer your question

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 I have added the stacktrace of error in the question description.

Comment: @Sam I have also tried adding \\ before localhost. It is also not working.

Comment: then you need to check you port number. As the error stacktrace doesn't seem to provide enough information.

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 What are the other options for port number ? How can I check port number ?

Comment: Well someone posted and deleted answer.I tested your code it works for me try either one of these `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "scott", "tiger");` or `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE", "scott", "tiger");` you need to add double quotes around username and password and by the way what's the version of database? I hope it's `Oracle 11g XE`

Comment: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" works fine. Thank you @Sam.

Comment: @Sam I am using Oracle 11g XE.

Comment: There is one parameter in `sqlnet.ora` `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_LISTENER = on` can work with both url's or if that parameter set to off or does not exist only second url works

Comment: `:@` - not `@:`. URL wrong as said ;)

Answer (score 7):

It is a typo, you misplaced the @:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin@:localhost:1521:XE"
```

It should be:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get some samples from github. Example., [DataSourceSample](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java)